# T-SQL import data and remove duplicate records from prior month

Tags: t-sql

Every month we receive a roster which we run queries on and then generate data that gets uploaded into a table for an outside source to retrieve. My question is what would be the easiest way to remove the duplicate data from the prior months upload bearing in mind that not all data is duplicated and that if a person does not appear on the new roster their prior month needs to remain. The data is time stamped when it gets uploaded.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cte and Row_Number() to identify and remove dupes

```
;with cte as (
    Select *
          ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By SomeKeyField(s) Order By SomeDate Desc)
    From   YourTable
)
Select *      -- << Remove if Satisfied
-- Delete     -- << Remove Comment if Statisfied
 From cte 
 Where RN>1
```

Without seeing your data structure, take a hard look a the Partition By and Order By within the OVER clause of Row_Number()

Comment: @Leigh.Page Happy to help.  Just make sure your Partition By and Order By is correct before you pull the trigger on the DELETE

Comment: @Leigh.Page Just making sure you grabbed the code >>> Where RN>1 <<<<  ... Originally I had a typo RN =1

Answer (score 0):

Short and efective way is delete via derived table.

```
delete from f
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by col order by (select 0)) rn
    from tbl) f
where rn > 1
```

But the most efective way is remove duplicates on input and prevent them (for example with unique constraint).

Comment: But the duplicate to be removed would be the one already present in the table. The new version with the most updated time stamp would replace it.

Comment: So add some order by column.

Comment: OK cool, good idea. Thank you for your help it is much appreciated.